# How to run my compiled python not the system installed one

Tags: python, make, openssl, ssl, python3

I have compiled python3.6.5 from the source and linked it to my compiled openssl as the following:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/openssl/lib/ -L/usr/local/openssl/lib64/"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/openssl/lib/:/usr/local/openssl/lib64/"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/openssl/include -I/usr/local/openssl/include/openssl"
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/openssl/
make
make install
```

And the openssl is installed as follows:

```
./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl shared zlib
make
make install
```

`/my/path/` in the above instructions is replaced with `/usr/local/openssl/` where openssl is also built in Ubuntu 18 but I compiled it from the source because the system one is missing some features I need.

Now, I want to run my python program using my compile python not the system one.
How to do this? If I write python `myprog.py`, it will run the system's python.

Comment: Isn't your compiled python under `/my/path`?

Comment: No. the compiled python is under the `home`. The two libraries are installed under the `home` directory as follows: `home/Python-3.6.5` and  `home/openssl-1.1.0g`. The /my/path/ that you see in my post has been replaced by `/usr/local/openssl/`. The OpenSSL library is configured like this: `./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl shared zlib` then `make` and `make install`

Comment: Rather than do it like this, why not use `virtualenv` or `venv`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html. Makes for a far simpler way to manage your own Pythons w/o having to re-invent wheels.

Comment: @slm I prefer normal settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your have a custom Python installed under `/some/path`:

1. Adding the shebang line in `myscript.py` will select the custom python when running it as executable script:

   ```
   #!/some/path/bin/python
   import sys
   print(sys.version)
   ```

   Running the script:

   ```
   $ chmod +x myscript.py
   $ ./myscript.py
   2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07)
   [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]
   ```
2. You can explicitly pass the path to python executable to run the script:

   ```
   $ /some/path/bin/python myscript.py
   ```
3. Prepending `/some/path/bin` to `PATH` will select the custom python instead of the system one:

   ```
   $ PATH=/some/path/bin:$PATH python myscript.py
   ```

Judging by the line `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/openssl/` you've provided, it looks like you installed custom Python under `/usr/local/openssl`; the bin dir should thus be `/usr/local/openssl/bin`.